# If I want to voice record at work, do I only need my boss's approval?

Tags: united-states, corporate-law, recording, consent, multiple-jurisdiction

I live in a two party consent state. I would like to record talks in work to defend myself from certain situations. I explained my intention to my boss and he said its perfectly fine. However sometimes my boss calls me to his table and not an empty room, so if I record such conversation other people talking could also make their way into the recordings. In this case do I need to ask every other employee in the room and get their explicit consent? Or is the approval of my boss enough regardless of 3rd parties in the background?

Answer (score 2):

If a party is aware that you are recording and they continue to be a party to the communication, they have implicitly consented.
Their leverage is that they can stop talking, not that they can absolutely stop you from recording. Physical location is not the determining factor so "being in the same room" is not the determinative factor. Instead, the question is whether the person is a party to the communication (not just "sitting nearby"). Implicit consent is widely recognized, see for Washington (one of the all-party consent states) [State v. Townsend](https://casetext.com/case/state-v-townsend-17), 147 Wn.2d 666, and there has to be a reasonable expectation of privacy ([State v. Clark](https://casetext.com/case/state-v-clark-420), 129 Wn.2d 211).

Consent (implicit or explicit) has to come from each party to each communication that you record. That means, first, that the boss cannot issue a blanket consent for all employees. Second, it means that you can only record the communication between you and your boss, and not separate communications between A and B, from whose perspective the recording is secret (therefore illegal). Whether or not recording in a room with two conversations taking place is a very fact-intensive question regarding the effectiveness of your public announcement, the physical nature of the other communications (sound pressure level), and your recording apparatus.